# Second level Top N SQL server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, top-n

I have a table with Names, Countries and Status. I want get total by grouping by Names and Status but get only Top 3 Countries.

My table:

```
+------+---------+--------+
| Name | Country | Status |
+------+---------+--------+
| ABC  | US      | Open   |
| ABC  | US      | Closed |
| ABC  | US      | Open   |
| ABC  | Japan   | Open   |
| ABC  | Japan   | Closed |
| ABC  | China   | Open   |
| ABC  | China   | Closed |
| ABC  | Italy   | Open   |
| DEF  | US      | Open   |
| DEF  | US      | Closed |
| DEF  | Japan   | Open   |
| DEF  | Japan   | Closed |
| DEF  | China   | Open   |
| DEF  | China   | Closed |
| DEF  | China   | Closed |
| DEF  | Italy   | Open   |
+------+---------+--------+
```

Desired output:

```
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| Name | Country | Status | Total |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| ABC  | US      | Open   |     2 |
| ABC  | US      | Closed |     1 |
| ABC  | Japan   | Open   |     1 |
| ABC  | Japan   | Closed |     1 |
| ABC  | China   | Open   |     1 |
| ABC  | China   | Closed |     1 |
| DEF  | US      | Open   |     1 |
| DEF  | US      | Closed |     1 |
| DEF  | Japan   | Open   |     1 |
| DEF  | Japan   | Closed |     1 |
| DEF  | China   | Open   |     1 |
| DEF  | China   | Closed |     2 |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
```

I tried the following query but it didn't give me result I am looking for.

```
Select rs.Name, rs.Country, rs.Status, Count(*) as total from (
SELECT Name, Country, Status, Rank() 
          over (Partition BY Name
                ORDER BY Country DESC ) AS Rank
        FROM table1 ) rs WHERE Rank <= 3
```

Comment: What happened to Italy?

Comment: I am looking for top 3 countries by count. If you take ABC - he has 3 US, 2 Japan, 2 China and only 1 Italy.

Comment: what is the default order that you have shown in original data it seems order by name but how are countries arranged??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
;With CTE AS (
   SELECT Name, Country, Status,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Country) AS cnt
   FROM mytable
), CTE2 AS (
   SELECT Name, Country, Status, 
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY cnt DESC, Country) AS seq
   FROM CTE
)
SELECT Name, Country, Status, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM CTE2
WHERE seq <= 3
GROUP BY Name, Country, Status
ORDER BY Name, Country
```

In case of the ties, the query picks the Country having the 'smallest' name in comparison to the other countries.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Your original query was definitely in the right direction (I even used it to figure out what output you wanted).  However, your desired output is the result of several aggregations, not just a single analytic function.  In the query below I first aggregate to get totals, then use rank to retain the first 3 groups.  In case of ties this query picks the country which comes alphabetically first.

```
SELECT t.Name,
       t.Country,
       t.Status,
       t.Total
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Name ORDER BY t.Total DESC, t.Country) AS rn
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Country, Status, COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Name, Country, Status
) t
WHERE rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
Select rs.Name, rs.Country, rs.Status, Count(*) as total from rs(
SELECT Name, Country, Status, Count(status) from mytable
    group by status order by Count(status) desc
 ) rs limit 3
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is for `MySQL`, OP asked it for `SQL-Server`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select Top 3 with ties * FROM(
select Name, country, Status
, count(*) as total
, count(*) over (Partition BY Name, Country) as rank
from mytable
group by Name, Country, Status
) i 
order by i.rank desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below SQL script

```
;with cte as (
    select *, COUNT(*) over (partition by country) cnt
    from table1
), t3 as (
    select distinct top 3 country, cnt
    from cte order by cnt desc
)
select distinct * 
from cte
inner join t3 on cte.country = t3.country
```

Output is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below query.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT NAME,COUNTRY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY COUNT(COUNTRY) DESC) ROWNO  FROM TBLCOUNTRY
    GROUP BY NAME,COUNTRY
)
SELECT C.NAME,C.COUNTRY,C.STATUS,COUNT(C.STATUS) TOTAL FROM TBLCOUNTRY C INNER JOIN CTE ON
C.NAME=CTE.NAME AND C.COUNTRY=CTE.COUNTRY AND CTE.ROWNO<=3
GROUP BY C.NAME,C.COUNTRY,C.STATUS
ORDER BY NAME,COUNTRY DESC, STATUS DESC
```